# Echo a php code with Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, hacklang

i whould like to know if am able to list the content of a php file if i know exactly the location of php file. Im am hoping that myJsonData will contain the php source code. I dont know why but i know that can work and if i know exactly the path/to/php file . Any sugestions ?  https://github.com/PalexM/Requetes-Ajax-back-et-front

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({ 
    // url: "test-ajax-update.php",
    type: "GET",
    url:"wp-config.php",
    success:function(e){console.log("ok")
    var myJsonData = JSON.parse(e);                                                                                                                                                                     }
})                                                                                                                                                                                                      });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What is the result of this AJAX call?  What's actually in `e`?  What's in `myJsonData`?  What did you expect?  Why?

Comment: No you cannot otherwise anyone could get any third party PHP source code

Comment: is nothing , i was hoping that myJsonData will contain the source code in text from the file wp-config.php . it show me in console my "ok" ,  thats mean the function is a succes but it return nothig ;

Comment: @PopAlexandru: *"but is return nothing"* - Well, where does your code *return* anything?  What *specifically* is the problem?  You're logging a string to the console and you're setting the value of a variable.  What other *output* did you expect?  Please clarify the actual problem.  It sounds like you *might* be asking how to view PHP source code from the client, or you *might* be asking how to return a response from an AJAX call, or you *might* be asking something else entirely.

Comment: The client is me , and yes , that i am trying to do. I know that if a php file dont have <?php ?> you can read from file whithout any problem with json encode and decode . i have a git that show you that this is posible https://github.com/PalexM/Requetes-Ajax-back-et-front

Answer (score 1):

You would use jQuery.get() to do this.

```
var phpContent = ""

$.get( "wp-config.php", function( data ) {
    phpContent = data
});
```

You now have a the data stored in a variable named phpContent, you can append that to an element or whatever you want to do with it.

Note that cross domain linking doesn't work all that well, but that's a question that been asked and answered many other Tims elsewhere on this site.